# Making merged lists out of several lists of lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe, iteration, nested-lists

I have four lists of lists each containing millions of data. The length of each individual list is always 2. e.g.,

```
L_1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [10,12]]
L_2 = [[5,9], [0,1]]
L_3 = [[3,5]]
L_4 = [[4,9]]
```

They always contain only integer values. I want to find all possible combinations of L_1 and L_2 considering two conditions: (1) in each list there shouldn't be a repeated value (e.g. [1,2,1,9] is not accepted), and (2) if we say [A,B] coming from L_1 and [C,D] from L_2, [A,B,C,D] is acceptable only if [A,C] is a list in L_3 and [B,D] is a list in L_4. So, given the above example, all possible combinations of L_1 and L_2 (the list orders are to be preserved, e.g. we CAN'T make [A,C,B,D] out of [A,B] & [C,D]) will lead to:

```
L_tot = [[1,2,5,9], [1,2,0,1], [3,4,5,9], [3,4,0,1], [10,12,5,9], [10,12,0,1]]
```

But only

```
Accepted = [3,4,5,9]
```

is acceptable.

this is my current code which gives the right results in the cost of LARGE memory usage:

```
df_tot = L_1.merge(L_2, how='cross')
df_tot = df_tot[~df_tot.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated().any(), axis=1)]
df_tot = df_tot.drop_duplicates()

df = pd.merge(df_tot, L_4, on=['B','D'], how="inner")
df = df.drop_duplicates()

df_ACBD = pd.merge(df, L_3, on=['A','C'], how="inner")
Accepted = df_ACBD.drop_duplicates()
```

So, what is the best way to do this efficiently (short time - less memory)? Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to understand if code used L_1...L_4 variable names. Wouldn't it be quicker to remove all elements from L_1 that are not in L_3, and remove all elements from L_2 that are not in L_4 and then use what is left to generate the ABCD list?

Comment: Please see the edited version. I think I have applied your suggestion in earlier steps of the code. So, the first element in all lists inside L_3 is a subset of the first elements of L_1, ....

Comment: Are `L_3` and `L_4` much smaller than `L_1` and `L_2` in size?

Comment: It depends. I am doing some mathematical tasks that in the output give that all pairs in L_1 and L_2 (i.e., they are valid pairs). I take all the first elements of L_1 and all the first elements of L_2 to make a PRE L_3. Using this pre L3, I check the pairs for that mathematical function. Some of these pairs will not be valid. So, if we say len(L_1)=100 and Len(L_2)=20, then len(L_3) < 100 * 20.

Comment: I continue to feel it would make sense to formulate this as External Sort using an RDBMS, where "external" refers to disk storage, contrasted to internal RAM storage. An on-disk Btree index datastructure can definitely help here. Something the question omits is how much entropy is in each integer pair. Are integers (nearly) unique? Or does the distribution heavily favor a couple of values? This will make a difference to the query planner. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization#Cost_estimation You want to join 1st element A against L_3, and 2nd element B against L4, for early pruning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `product` from itertools and check your conditions with some if statements

Comment: I have tried. This is not going to be quick, we are speaking about millions of lists.

Comment: Ah I see, did you try to prune your list before running the loop. Like you only keep the elements in your lists that verify your conditions and then you look at the product ?

Comment: Also could you share a code with what you already tried ?

Comment: Please see the edited version.